# Do i have to register enqueue scripts and style in css?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Is it a valid code as below?

```
function medical_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css');

  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js',     array('jquery'));

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'medical_scripts' );
```

or do i have to register first for each of the style and script using `wp_register_style()` and `wp_register_script()` respectively?

which method is recommended and why? it seems like it is less coding for the first method.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to use `wp_register_style()` or `wp_register_script()` in order for that code to work.

I recommend just using the `wp_enqueue_*` functions so you don't have the extra code. There may be certain situations where you would want to register the script beforehand but I think in most common situations you will be just fine with enqueue-ing at the time needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using  the `wp register style()` is a **safe way** to register a CSS style file for later use with `wp_enqueue_style()`. But you have to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action to call this function. Calling it outside of an action can lead to problems.

The similar is also true for `wp_register_script()` - it registers a script file in WordPress to be linked to a page **later** using the `wp_enqueue_script()` function, which **safely handles the script dependencies**.

Scripts that have been pre-registered using `wp_register_script()` **do not need to be manually enqueued** using `wp_enqueue_script()` if they are listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued. WordPress will **automatically** include the registered script before it includes the enqueued script that lists the registered script's handle as a dependency.